# Choosing among alternatives in a Haskell algebraic datatype

Tags: data-structures, haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

When type `X` is defined as:

```
data X = 
    X { sVal :: String } |
    I { iVal :: Int } |
    B { bVal :: Bool }
```

and I want the `Int` inside an `X` value, if there is one, otherwise zero.

```
returnInt :: X -> Int
```

How can I determine which type of `X` the argument to `returnInt` is?

Comment: To add some further inside, your definition basically says that the type X is either a type constructor X OR a type constructor I OR a type constructor B.  Your function takes any of the members of X, so you can just pattern match I, which is a member of X.

Comment: @codebliss: Minor nitpick: those three are data constructors. A *type* constructor is, for example `Maybe`, which has a kind of `* -> *`: apply one type to it and you get a concrete type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify a point here, let me rewrite your data type to avoid ambiguities in the meaning of X:

```
data SomeType = X { myString :: String} | I {myInt :: Int} | B {myBool :: Bool}
```

In this definition there are no X, I and B types. X, I and B are **constructors that create a value of type** `Sometype` . Note what happens when you ask ghci what is the type of any value constructed with those type constructors:

```
*Main> :t (I 5)
(I 5) :: Sometype 

*Main> :t (B False)
(B False) :: Sometype
```

They belong to the same type!!

Just as you can use X, I and B to construct types, you can use pattern matching to deconstruct the type, like done in the other answers above:

```
returnInt :: SomeType -> Int 
returnInt (I x) = x        -- if the pattern matches (I x) then return x
returnInt _  = error "I need an integer value, you moron"  -- throw an error otherwise
```

Just remember that pattern matching occurs in order: if the value matches the pattern in some line, the patterns in lines below that will not be executed.

Note that when you define your type like you did, using what is called Record Syntax (just look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes ), you got functions like that for free!!

Try looking on the type of myInt, for example:

```
*Main> :t myInt
myInt :: SomeType -> Int
```

And look what this function do:

```
*Main> myInt (I 5)
5

*Main> myInt (B False)
*** Exception: No match in record selector Main.myInt
```

This is exactly the behavior of `returnInt` above defined. The strange error message just tells you that the function don't know how to deal with a member of the type SomeType that doesn't match `(I x)`.

If you define your type using the more common syntax:

```
data SomeType2 = X String | I Int | B Bool
```

then you loose those nice record functions.

The error messages terminate the execution of the program. This is annoying sometimes. If you need safer behavior for your functions GBacon's answer is just the way to do it. Learn about the `Maybe a` type and use it to cope with this kind of computation that need to return some value or return nothing ( try this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Hierarchical_libraries/Maybe ).

Answer (score 13):

Use pattern matching.

```
returnInt :: X -> Int
returnInt (I x) = x
returnInt _     = 0
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a more flexible definition for all possible `X` values:

```
returnInt :: X -> Maybe Int
returnInt (I i) = Just i
returnInt _ = Nothing
```

Then you can use [`maybe`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:maybe) for the particular defaulting you want—0 might be a valid value (this is known as the [semipredicate problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semipredicate_problem)):

```
*Main> maybe 0 id (returnInt $ X "")
0
*Main> maybe 0 id (returnInt $ I 123)
123
*Main> maybe (-1) id (returnInt $ X "yo")
-1
```

In contrast, partial functions risk runtime exceptions:

```
*Main> let returnInt (I i) = i
*Main> :t returnInt
returnInt :: X -> Int
*Main> returnInt (B True)
*** Exception: <interactive>:1:4-22: Non-exhaustive patterns in function returnInt
```

If you're feeling really froggy, you could use `MonadPlus`

```
returnInt :: (MonadPlus m) => X -> m Int
returnInt (I i) = return i
returnInt _ = mzero
```

to gain even more flexibility:

```
*Main> maybe 0 id (returnInt $ X "")
0
*Main> maybe 0 id (returnInt $ I 123)
123
*Main> returnInt (I 123) `mplus` returnInt (I 456) :: [Int]
[123,456]
```

Comment: In your last example you use `MonadPlus` for it's `mzero` method. In designing a library recently I ran into this situation and decided that returning a value in the `Monad` class by using `return` and `fail` was a better choice than using `MonadPlus`. I know `fail` is seen by some as a wart, but I decided using that was a better generalization since we would be using `MonadPlus` only for its mzero method. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @jberryman It depends on the context. My general preference is for whichever produces a nicer abstraction as measured by more elegant code for the library user. Your question would make an interesting community wiki!

Answer (score 4):

Given a function like this:

```
returnInt :: X -> Int
returnInt x = {- some integer -}
```

...the type of `x` is always `X`. What you care about is whether `x` uses the `X`, `I` or `B` type constructor.

Use pattern matching to tell the difference:

```
returnInt :: X -> Int
returnInt (X _) = error "needed an Int, got a String"
returnInt (I { iVal = n }) = n
returnInt (B _) = error "needed an Int, got a Bool"
```