# Appropriate uses of Monad `fail` vs. MonadPlus `mzero`

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monadplus

This is a question that has come up several times for me in the design code, especially libraries. There seems to be [some interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861432/choosing-among-alternatives-in-a-haskell-algebraic-datatype/1861554#1861554) in it so I thought it might make a good community wiki.

The `fail` method in Monad is considered by some to be a wart; a somewhat arbitrary addition to the class that does not come from the original category theory. But of course in the current state of things, many Monad types have logical and useful `fail` instances.

The MonadPlus class is a sub-class of Monad that provides an `mzero` method which logically encapsulates the idea of failure in a monad.

So a library designer who wants to write some monadic code that does some sort of failure handling can choose to make his code use the `fail` method in Monad or restrict his code to the MonadPlus class, just so that he can feel good about using `mzero`, even though he doesn't care about the monoidal combining `mplus` operation at all.

Some discussions on this subject are in this wiki page about [proposals to reform the MonadPlus class.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus_reform_proposal)

---

So I guess I have one specific question:

*What monad instances, if any, have a natural `fail` method, but cannot be instances of MonadPlus because they have no logical implementation for `mplus`?*

But I'm mostly interested in a discussion about this subject. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: One final thought occured to me. I recently learned (even though it's right there in the docs for `fail`) that monadic "do" notation is desugared in such a way that pattern match failures, as in `(x:xs) <- return []` call the monad's `fail`.

It seems like the language designers must have been strongly influenced by the prospect of some automatic failure handling built in to haskell's syntax in their inclusion of `fail` in Monad.

Comment: It’s an ill-posed question, but probably one that in the answering will help clarify things. The most important step is to decide what algebraic laws MonadPlus should follow, but it's also worth thinking about what programmers might expect fail and mzero to do.

Comment: I think I'm really just inviting a discussion about the inclusion of `fail` in Monad, and perhaps an expansion on the vein of discussion in the MonadPlus wiki discussion page above. Maybe my answer can be edited to better serve that goal.

Comment: Oh, most people don't like fail and think it should not live in Monad :-)

Comment: Changed tag [class] to [typeclass], as class is used almost exclusively for OO programming. Haskellers usually use the [typeclass] tag.

Answer (score 11):

Think of `Either`. It's monadic instance looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance Monad (Either String) where
  (Left x) >>= _   = Left x
  (Right a)  >>= f = f a
  return           = Right
  fail             = Left
```

(We need *FlexibleInstances* in order to allow an instance like `Either String`)
So it's basically like `Maybe` with an optional error message if something happens. You can't recreate this with `mzero`, as you can't add an error message to the failure. It's somewhat different from `fail`.

Each instance of `mplus` should satisfy these two laws:

```
mzero `mplus` a -> a
a `mplus` mzero -> a
```

Simple, isn't it? But these laws make `mplus` special. With them, it's possible to write a reasonable `MonadPlus` instance for it:

```
instance MonadPlus (Either a) where
  mzero = Left undefined
  mplus (Left _) b = b
  mplus a _        = a
```

What is this? It represents a choice. If the first computation is successful, it will be returned. Else, `mplus` returns the second computation. Note how it differs from `(>>)`, which doesn't satisfies the laws:

```
Left a   >>    Right b -> Left a
Left a `mplus` Right b -> Right b
```

`(>>)` will stop on the first computation, while `mplus` tries the second one instead. `[]` also behaves like this:

```
[] >> [1..4] -> []
[] `mplus` [1..4] -> [1,2,3,4]
```

This is just to discuss the aspects of `MonadPlus` and specially the aspect of `mplus` in contrast to `(>>)`.

Comment: Oh, duh. Trying not to short-cirtuit in `(Left a) >>= f = ...` necessitates inventing an argument. Even when that gets ignored by `(>>)`, it makes the Monad instance right-out evil. So while it may be possible to derive `mplus`, it cannot be (reliably) done in a way not introducing non-totality, that is, it cannot be done sensibly. That said, I think you meant to return `x` instead of `a` in your second code line.

Comment: I think you mean `x@(Left _) >>= _ = x`, not `x@(Left a) >>= _ = a` (since a is a `String` not an `Either String t` for some type `t`)

Comment: Yes. Fixed that typo. Already prepared for this using `@`, but then entered the wrong character.

Comment: Try to type-check your Monad instance. It has a syntax bug and a type error.

Comment: @Peaker: Fixed it. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `fail` was split into a separate type class [`MonadFail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html) in the newly released GHC 8 (base 4.9). Now we can define `instance MonadFail (Either String) where fail = Left`, `instance String ~ a => MonadFail (Either a)` or [what ever the case may be](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12160).

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, I want to discuss the topic, why `fail` isa  member of `Monad`. I don't want to add this to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023969/appropriate-uses-of-monad-fail-vs-monadplus-mzero/5029561#5029561), since it covers another topic.

---

Although the mathematical definition of a monad doesn't contains `fail`, the creators of Haskell 98 put it into the `Monad` typeclass. Why?

In order to ease the usage of monads and to make it easier to abstract the usage of monads, they introduced the `do` notation, a very useful piece of sugar. For example, this code:

```
do putStr "What's your full name? "
   [name,surname] <- getLine >>= return . words
   putStr "How old are you? "
   age <- getLine >>= return . read
   if age >= 18
      then putStrLn $ "Hello Mr / Ms " ++ surname
      else putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ name
```

translates to:

```
putStr "What's your full name? " >>
getLine >>= return . words >>= \[name,surname] ->
putSr "How old are you? " >>
getLine >>= return . read >>= \age ->
if age >= 18
   then putStrLn $ "Hello Mr / Ms " ++ surname
   else putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ name
```

What's the problem here? Imagine you have a name with a space in between, like *Jon M. Doe*. In this case, the whole construct will be `_|_`. Sure, you can work around this by adding some ad-hoc function with `let`, but this is pure boilerplate. At the time Haskell 98 was created, there wasn't an exception system like today, where you could simply catch the failed pattern matching. Also, incomplete patterns are considered bad coding style.

What's the solution? The creators of Haskell 98 added a special function `fail`, called in the case of a mismatch. The desugaring looks somewhat like this:

```
putStr "What's your full name? " >> let
  helper1 [name,surname] =
    putSr "How old are you? " >> let
      helper2 age =
        if age >= 18
           then putStrLn $ "Hello Mr / Ms " ++ surname
           else putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ name
      helper2 _ = fail "..."
    in getLine >>= return . read >>= helper2
  helper1 _ = fail "..."
in getLine >>= return . words >>= helper1
```

(I'm not sure whether there is really a `helper2`, but I think so)

If you look twice at this, you'll find out how smart it is. First, there's never an incomplete pattern match, and second you can make `fail` configurizable. To achieve this, they just put `fail` into the monads definition. For example, for `Maybe`, `fail` is simply `Nothing` and for the instance of `Either String`, it's `Left`. This way, it's easy to write monad-independent monadic code. For instance, for a long time `lookup` was defined as `(Eq a,Monad b) => a -> [(a, b)] -> m b`, and `lookup` returned `fail` if there wasn't a match.

Now, there's still the big question in the Haskell community: isn't it a bad idea to add something completely independent to the `Monad` typeclass like `fail`? I can't answer this question, but IMHO this decision was right, as other places aren't that comfortable for `fail`.

Comment: I still don't buy that `fail` must be in `Monad`, instead of its own class, to enable that. I absolutely wouldn't mind getting compiler errors along the lines of `No instance for (Failure Foo) arising from an incomplete pattern match in do notation at <whereever>`. It might not fit particularly well into existing compiler pipelines, though.

Comment: If it would be in another class, the behavior would depend on whether there is an instance of this class. Or you would be forced to declare an instance to use the sugar. This could change the meaning of your code, if some jerk would define an instance of that class in some other module. Also notice, that instances are like a virus, once defined they're valid everywhere. Also, for performance issues all instances of classes are static and known before execution. There isn't a runtime check "am I instance of Foo" while running. This kind of static typing is a basic attribute of Haskell.

Comment: what would change is not the dynamic behaviour: Incomplete pattern matches would be a *compile-time* error when the instance is missing, no run-time checks involved, so the only thing that jerk can do is make non-compiling code compile (Or the other way round if he introduces a duplicate instance, but that's the case for `Monad`, too). If you want a yet higher degree of security, there's always `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`.

Comment: @barsoap: I don't wan't to start a flame. Personally, I like it as it is. I think it's mostly a matter of taste and whether you like mathematical correctness or pragmatism.